# Will time in a non-emergency medical transport driving job help a med school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, medicine

As a driver at a non-emergency medical transport company, it’s a person’s job to complete the process of moving patients in walkers and wheelchairs from place to place. This occasionally entails assisting movement from bed to chair and typically involves wheeling the patent from the room to the van, attaching their chair to the van, and wheeling the patient from the van to their medical appointment or new place of residence.

Many med schools look for volunteer medical experience or shadowing. Would the above described job fulfill this requirement? If not, would it help a med school application significantly in any way?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to understand about the medical school admissions process is that they can quickly and broadly screen applicants based on numerical data such as MCAT scores and GPA. This is the "first cut", so to speak. After that, they're looking for interesting human beings, as much as can be determined from a paper application. Your transport job sounds like it fulfills the soft requirement of knowing something about what dealing with sick people is like. It probably isn't going to help "significantly" unless you can describe the experience in a compelling way. You get a short little space to put in a quick blurb about what you did. Statistically speaking, you're unlikely to write anything that would catch someone's eye. That's the cold hard truth when you're looking through a thousand applications, AFTER cutting out the other 10,000 based on MCAT, GPA, and whatever. On the plus slide, most applicants are going to be writing about volunteering in hospital or working in a research lab, but you have the opportunity to stand out! Try and make the most out of it, but temper your expectations. If resources were infinite, most medical schools could easily accommodate many more students than they currently do. If you don't get in the first time, try again!